# Logoff a special user via batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Can logoff or sing out a special user in domain from server via batch file?

like : `shutdown -r -m \\target computer`

Comment: So you want to manually execute this on a server to log out a user? See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/650816/log-off-a-disconnected-user-remotely) on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to run via batch file, you have to authenticate first, so I assume you have the credentials for that specific user/domain admin user, so I'd recommend using wmic.exe(using RPC):

```
wmic /node:"ServerHostname" /user:"DomainName\DomainAdmin" /password:"DomainAdminPass" process call create "shutdown -l -t 0"
```

There are many other ways to do this in a domain like performing a "net use" to authenticate and than creating and running a service via sc.exe or at.exe/authenticating via schtasks.exe and creating a schedule tasks that can run remotely.